# how to auto populate text fields with text automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple Registration form and I want to make an option like there are two different fields, and what i want is simple, just when I add text to the first field it should automatically be added the same content to the next field.

Comment: should I use any Jquery script or Java Script at all for this, and if any of you knows already something like this please I would really appreciate it!

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, if you already have it included on your page by all means use it. Otherwise, if your project doesn't use any jQuery yet and you don't plan to use it, there's no need for it either.

Comment: Word of the day: `Auto populate` :D

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#field1").change(function(){
    $("#field2").val(this.value);
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/CcDv4/**

Comment: I tried to put this code inside the <script> tags and i changed the field id to the one i have but its not working :S,, is it like i have to make a seperate function for this or what should i do exactly?

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#txt1').on('change', function(e){
        $('#txt2').val($(this).val());
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/GUeCD/3/)

Comment: Yes, thanks ! I was obsessed to the OP's question `it should automatically be added the same content to the next field.`

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event only fires when 2 conditions are met:

- The element loses focus;
- The element has a different `value` property than when it got focus.

If you want the text to change as you type it, you can use jQuery together with the HTML5 `input` event:

```
//assuming `a` and `b` as text field IDs
$('#a').on('input', function() {
   $('#b').val($(this).val());
});​
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/QTcGS/)

For non-HTML5 browsers, you can just extend the events map to simulate the `input` event:

```
$('#a').on('input keydown keypress keyup change blur', function() {
    $('#b').val($(this).val());
 });​
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/QTcGS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Give onchange event for first field and assign value for second field,as below

```
onchange="secondfieldname.value=firstfieldnamefieldname.value"
```